# Please again probability question?

Tags: probability

We have https://i.stack.imgur.com/HG4R7.jpg where K=0.3
I have to find F(X) which is the density of the probabilities of X..how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You're given the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$, i.e. the probabilities
$$
P(X=x,Y=y),\quad x=2,4,\quad y=-3,-1,1.
$$
In order to obtain the marginal probabilities of $X$, i.e. $P(X=x)$ you simply sum out $Y$. Mathematically this is obtained by
$$
P(X=x)=\sum_{y}P(X=x,Y=y).\tag{1}
$$
So if you were to find $P(X=2)$, then $(1)$ becomes
$$
P(X=2)=P(X=2,Y=-3)+P(X=2,Y=-1)+P(X=2,Y=1),
$$
which just corresponds to finding the row sums of your table.

Comment: so F= P(X=2) + P(x=4)?

Comment: but if F= P(X=2) + P(X=4) then F=1 :/

Comment: how about P(x=4)?

Comment: You obtain $P(X=4)$ in exactly the same manner (replacing $2$ by $4$) in my answer. I think what is meant by $F$ is the probability function, so when you have calculated $P(X=2)$ and $P(X=4)$, then you are done.

Comment: You mean calculate them apart ? Stil doesnt make sense to me :/

Comment: because when you calculate P(X=4) you still calculate Y during P(X=2,Y=-3) + P(X=2,Y=-1) +...

Comment: I use the joint probabilities of $X$ and $Y$, which is explicitly given in your table. Are you not able to add the three numbers together?

Comment: I am ,I am ,thank you.

Comment: What I wasnt understanding was that there are two different F's, one for P(X=2) and one for P(X=4)..

Comment: Ok, well first of all I am not entirely sure what u mean by the sentence "I have to find F(X) which is the density of the probabilities of X." but I thought you meant to find the [probability mass function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function). The probability mass function is the function $p$ assigning to each $x$ the probability $P(X=x)$, i.e. $p(x):=P(X=x)$. Now, this is a function and hence it has different values for different values of $x$. That is why you need to calculate it for $x=2$ and $x=4$ seperately.

Comment: probability mass function,that's right.Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome.